# Multiple Rows with null values to columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark and I have the next issue:

This is my input:

| ID | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 2/1/2022 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | null |

My desire output would be like this:

| ID | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 | 2/1/2022 |

I try joining the table to itselft and do a select distinct

Comment: Group by ID and agg using max: `df.groupBy("ID").agg(*[F.max(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c!='ID']).show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would like to aggregate and have one line per ID while ignoring null values?

Here's my answer:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
df = df.groupBy("ID").agg(
    first("Date 1", ignorenulls=True).alias("Date 1"),
    first("Date 2", ignorenulls=True).alias("Date 2"),
)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

This will however only return one line per ID.
If you have multiple non-null choices for Date1 and Date2, then it is better to use `max` and `min` or any other deterministic functions.